# OpenCV iOS : store Keypoints and Descriptors in file or any other

Tags: ios, opencv, descriptor, keypoint

Can any one help me to store the keypoints and descriptors get from the OpenCV in iOS. I tried for NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary, NSUserdefault , but not got success. Secondly is it possible to store as file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openCV framework in xCode you can use 'std::vector' to store keypoints and descriptors. For this to work .m file should be save as .mm file and dont forget to use 'using namespace std'.

Comment: Ya I am using OpenCV only. I already converted all the files to .mm . But the problem is how to store all the keypoints and descriptors in a single file and then fetch one by one at the time of matching. Scenario is I have 100 Images and I scanned an Image from camera to find perfect match in those 100 images with optimised time.

Comment: One way to do that is extract key points and descriptors of image from camera try to match them with the features of each image from the 100 images linearly. Every time you try to match an image extract the features of that and if not a match discard them and move on to next image. I know linear search in this case could result worst time case. If you have any other data about the 100 images you could filter your search images to reduce the search time.

Answer (score 0):

save file:

```
-(void)saveKeyPointsImage:(NSString *)imageName keyPoints:(vector<KeyPoint>)keys{
FileStorage fs("keypoints.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
write(fs , string([imageName UTF8String]), keys);
fs.release();
}
```

read file:

```
-(vector<KeyPoint>)getKeyPointsImage:(NSString *)imageName{
vector<KeyPoint> keys;
FileStorage fs2("keypoints.yml", FileStorage::READ);
FileNode kptFileNode = fs2[string([imageName UTF8String])];
read( kptFileNode, keys );
fs2.release();
return keys;
}
```

link to [http://answers.opencv.org/](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4040/to-save-vector-keypoint-to-file-using-builtin-write-function/)

Comment: I stored keypoints and descriptors in XML file and then just loaded them into vectors - I just uploaded samples from few projects maybe you will find something useful there:
https://github.com/SparingSoftware/ImageDetect-openCV